# Could not get type information for app.dataset

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've been stuck on this issue for some time now, i have connected to to an Azure database then created a dataset by adding a new data source.
But whenever i try to preview the data in one of the tables this error messeges

> Could not get type information for app.dataset

The error message pops up whenever that dataset is created, and this error message pops up when i run this code

```
var q = (from ev in db.Events
                 where ev.Id != 0
                 select ev.Title).First().ToString();            

        string e = q;

            tv.Text = e;
```

> Sequence contains no elements

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem with Visual Studio 15 and a regular SQL server. The `Connection string` was stored in my settings file. I had copied the file from another project and made small adjustments to it.

**Deleting the copied settings file and creating a fresh one solved the problem.** Apparently some incorrect data was copied also, even tho the settings file looked just fine.